# Replace string by 3 patterns "space", "and", "or"

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript

I am working on a project in Angular 6 and I need to replace a string by 3 patterns, "space", "and", and "or" by using replace method with regular expression. I am able to do it with "and" and "or", but not by adding "space". The user would enter words in the searchbox separated by any of the 3 patterns.

This works:

```
const value = new RegExp(searchValue.toLowerCase().replace(/ and | or /g, '|'));

// Input: apple and pear or corn
// Output: /apple|pear|corn/
```

This doesn't work:

```
const value = new RegExp(searchValue.toLowerCase().replace(/ \S+ | and | or /g, '|'));
```

I know that in order to replace by space you do `.replace(/ /g, '|'))`, but I need the space in the same method with "and" and "or".

How can this be accomplished? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use this as a regex ` and | or | \s*` although this select all subsequent spaces

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This worked:  const value = new RegExp(searchVal.toLowerCase().replace(/ and | or |\s+/g, '|'));

Comment: My pleasure. Have fun on SO.

Answer (score 5):

Use \s+ at the end of regex

**Mistake 1:** You used \S for space instead of \s.

> \S Matches a character other than white space. Equivalent to [^ \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff].

**Mistake 2:** You used \s at the beginning of regex

```
const value = new RegExp(searchValue.toLowerCase().replace(/ and | or |\s+/g, '|'));
```

```js
let searchValue = "apple and pear or corn banana"
const value = new RegExp(searchValue.toLowerCase().replace(/ and | or |\s+/g, '|'));

console.log(value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. I guess the order matters. When I had \s+ at the begging of regex, it didn't give me the results I was expecting.